# Prove Trigonometric identities:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Prove**: I am trying to find the identities.

> $$\sec(cos (x-1)^2-\cos(sec (a)^2 = \cos(a)\tan(a)^2$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? What happen when you write $\sec(a)$ and $\tan(a)$ in terms of $\cos(a)$ and $\sin(a)$?

Comment: I have tried to prove the identites and I can't get start...

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing

$$\sec a-\cos a=\frac{1}{\cos a}-\cos a=\frac{1-\cos^2a}{\cos a}$$

Now, use the fact that $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$.

Can you proceed? If not, please leave a comment with you work and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{L.H.S.}=\sec a - \cos a$$ $$= \frac{1}{\cos a}-\cos a$$ $$ = \frac{1-\cos^2 a}{\cos a}$$ $$=\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos a}$$ $$=\sin a \cdot \frac{\sin a}{\cos a}$$ $$=\sin a\tan a$$ $$=\text{R.H.S.}$$